# How to use a date constant for a BQL query filter

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to get a recordset via a BQL query, but I can't figure out how to create a constant for a date.  I'd like to filter based on a hard date value - but I see no examples anywhere for a date constant.  I tried using a string constant with the date value, but that did not work, and if I try to use a DateTime as such:

```
public const DateTime TranDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-04-01");

public class tranDate : Constant<DateTime>
{
    public tranDate() : base(TranDate) { }
}
```

I get an error - "cannot declare instance members in a static class".

I'm at a loss on this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following syntax to declare your date constant:

```
public class myDate : Constant<DateTime>
{
    public myDate()
        : base(new DateTime(2017, 04, 01))
    {
    }
}
```

For details see [Acumatica BQL constants reference](http://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=020c2e17-8909-4c3c-acdb-6321c51e1a36)